# Reactive Screen value - using Record Choice Set component

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

I have a screen flow with 2 components on the same screen:

1. Product choice - Picklist component that uses Record Choice Set (Product object) in order to choose a product record from a dropdown list.
2. Quantity.

When I defined the Record Choice Set - I store the product price__c on variable named varProductPrice.
I want to be able to do some custom logic based on that varProductPrice, and show in the same screen the total calculated price.

Is it possible ?
I tried using a formula (varProductPrice*varQuantity) and the varProductPrice is empty.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the "advanced" settings on the component used to present this value?

Comment: Hi - on which component ? I can't find this option ..

Comment: The component where you present the result of the formula...?

Comment: There's is no advanced in this component - it's display text component which shows the formula (price*quantity)

Comment: Have you followed the [instructions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_build_make_reactive.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Indeed. Have you tried to reproduce my request and it worked for you ?

Comment: I have not tried to reproduce; I was simply suggesting things I've seen cause issues before.

Comment: Got it. I think there might be an issue with showing a value from Record Choice Set, and that maybe it's not yet supported as reactive values.